# How do I add scrollbars to a ZedGraphWeb control?

Tags: zedgraph

I was able to get to the zedgraph wiki via wayback machine, but I'm not seeing any info on it. Is it even possible to add scrolling to the **web version** of the zedgraph control?

Answer (score 0):

Use `IsShowHScrollBar` and `IsShowVScrollBar` of `ZedGraphControl` Class. See [API](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_ZedGraphControl.htm) (search for "scroll") for further properties concerning scrolling.

Comment: That's part of the ZedGraphControl object. I'm specifically talking about the ZedGraphWeb control object. I'm starting to think it's not possible.

Comment: Ok, sorry, i didn't knew that there is a difference.